# I can't display my product angular firebase error interface is 'undefined'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, interface

I have defined my interface inside product-detail page but still it doesnt recognise the interface.
Cutit: undefined , but I defined and imported my interface ?
Error log: [image]

```
produse.service.ts

  bayonetDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<CutiteInterface>;

 getBayoneteSolo(id: string) {
    this.bayonetDoc = this.afStore.doc<CutiteInterface>(`bayonete/${id}`);
    return this.bayonetDoc.valueChanges();
  }
```

Here i call my single product by id , but i can't get the interface informations..

```
product-details.page.ts

import { CutiteInterface } from "src/app/produse.model";

Cutit: CutiteInterface;

ngOnInit(){
    this.CutitBayonet();
    console.log(this);
}

  CutitBayonet() {
    const ID = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");
    return this.ProduseService.getBayoneteSolo(ID).subscribe(
      (data) => (this.Cutit = data)
    );
  }
```

```
// this is the interface
export interface CutiteInterface {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  stoc: boolean;
  price: number;
  reducere: number;
  image: string;
  tag: string;
  userId: string;
}
```

And this is where i call HTML:

```
 <div class="product_descriere">
   {{ Cutit.description }} 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `this.CutitBayonet()` and immediately logging `this` to console. So obviously `Cutit` will be `undefined`. Initial value of `Cutit` is undefined until the data is returned from the **Asynchronous** function call.

`Cutit` will only get a value once the data is returned from Firebase.

Also in the template use safe navigation operator(`?`) like so:

```html
 <div class="product_descriere">
   {{ Cutit?.description }} 
 </div>
```

Comment: Ok im blurreed.. i don't know what to do to change my situation. Can you please show me an example ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally ... fixed my solution with my old function.

I just needed to declare object from interface

```
Cutit: CutiteInterface
```

and use this function inside ngOnInit();

```
  this.bayonetID = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");
    this.ProduseService.GetBayonete().subscribe((products) => {
      this.Cutit = products.find((a) => a.id === this.bayonetID);
      return this.Cutit, console.log(this.Cutit);
    });
```

Thank you all for your support!